# How can I enable rEFIt boot volume choice after waking up from hibernation mode?

Tags: bootcamp, efi, hibernate

There are pretty clear answers to the question 'How to put my Mac into hibernation mode voluntary', but there is still an issue for me.

I use Bootcamp Windows and [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) to select which sistem to load. But when I wake from the hibernation mode I have no option to choose - just Mac OS is loading. How can I enable boot source choose after waking up from the hibernation mode?

Answer (score -2):

Here seems to be a good explanation of the process.
Might be a tad old though :)

http://blog.yasmar.net/2006/05/make-refit-and-safe-sleep-play-well-together/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: You are totally correct and this is a good example of why that is so, as the link is dead and beyond repair.